# Can a reformer model really handle long-range dependency?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, transformer, attention-mechanism, huggingface

I read this [article](https://huggingface.co/blog/reformer) about new attention model called [Reformer](https://github.com/patrickvonplaten/notebooks/blob/master/PyTorch_Reformer.ipynb). Here is the main strength of this model:

> The Reformer pushes the limit of longe sequence modeling by its ability to process up to half a million tokens at once as shown in this demo.

Is it actually true? Because later in jupyter notebook I see the following in a config:

```
config = {
    "attention_head_size": 64,
    "attn_layers": ["local", "lsh", "local", "lsh", "local", "lsh"],
    "lsh_attn_chunk_length": 64,
    "local_attn_chunk_length": 64,

    "lsh_num_chunks_before": 1,
    "lsh_num_chunks_after": 0,
    "local_num_chunks_before": 1,
    "local_num_chunks_after": 0,
}
```

This config tells that they use chunks, so attention can span only `64` tokens and 1 chunk before it.

Does it mean that there is no any long-range dependency can be learned by this model?